# Assigning intersecting line length dependent value to raster during polyline conversion using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, convert, road

I am converting a road network polyline into raster format- my polyline shapefile has an exhaust emissions rate attribute which is in kg/km

What I want to achieve is a raster that has (at say 5m resolution) cells with computed emission values that are a function of the length of road that falls within the cell times the emission rate.

For example, for a cell of 5m if the road line intersects at 45 degrees through each corner of the cell the raster value should be the emission rate times 7.1 (a^2+b^2=c^2)- at the moment ArcMap is just taking the raw emission rate and making no correction for geometry.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a polygon layer that is a 5m grid over your original polyline layer and then intersect these 2 layers. This will give you a length of road within your 5m cell. Join that information back to the polygon grid layer and rasterize this layer, this then becomes your layer to multiple your rasterized road network with.

If you have ArcMap then search for "fish nets".